# Проблема авторизации пользователя

Tags: c#, vknet

Есть метод, который получает отформатированные *login, pass, appID, token*, по которым дальше происходит авторизация. Для примера возьму мой акк. Ввожу нужные данные в форме, они приходят в ниже приведённый метод, начинается авторизация, т.к. у меня *включена 2fa*, вылезает окно, которое просит секретный код. Всё идёт хорошо, *код !приходит!*, я ввожу, он уходит и *вылетает ошибка*, что *логин или пароль были введёны неверно*. Пробовал много раз, код ввожу я правильно, *капча не вылазит*, на всякий случай, заранее обработал её. Не пойму, что не так. Пробовал с разных [приложений](https://vk.com/apps?act=manage) заходить, тоже результата 0. Я уже думаю, что это ограничение от ВК, не знаю, что делать. Буду рад любой информации, заранее благодарю.

[image: Ошибка]

```
private void UserAuth(string login, string pass, ulong appID, PopupAuth.TwoFactorSupported token)
{
    ulong? captcha_sid = null;
    string captcha_key = null;

    try
    {
        if (token == PopupAuth.TwoFactorSupported.Supported)
        {
            try
            {
                api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams() //вылетает тут
                {
                    Login = login,
                    Password = pass,
                    ApplicationId = appID,
                    TwoFactorSupported = true,
                    TwoFactorAuthorization = SecretCode,
                    TokenExpireTime = 0,
                    CaptchaSid = captcha_sid,
                    CaptchaKey = captcha_key,
                    Settings = Settings.All
                });
            }
            catch (CaptchaNeededException ex) when (ex.Data != null)
            {
                captcha_sid = ex.Sid;
                CaptchaForm captcha = new CaptchaForm(ex.Img);
                captcha.ShowDialog();
                captcha_key = captcha.GetCaptchaKey;

                api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams()
                {
                    Login = login,
                    Password = pass,
                    ApplicationId = appID,
                    TwoFactorSupported = true,
                    TwoFactorAuthorization = SecretCode,
                    TokenExpireTime = 0,
                    CaptchaSid = captcha_sid,
                    CaptchaKey = captcha_key,
                    Settings = Settings.All
                });
            }
        }
        else if (token == PopupAuth.TwoFactorSupported.NotSupported)
        {
            try
            {
                api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams()
                {
                    Login = login,
                    Password = pass,
                    ApplicationId = appID,
                    TokenExpireTime = 0,
                    CaptchaSid = captcha_sid,
                    CaptchaKey = captcha_key,
                    Settings = Settings.All
                });
            }
            catch (CaptchaNeededException ex) when (ex.Data != null)
            {
                captcha_sid = ex.Sid;
                CaptchaForm captcha = new CaptchaForm(ex.Img);
                captcha.ShowDialog();
                captcha_key = captcha.GetCaptchaKey;

                api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams()
                {
                    Login = login,
                    Password = pass,
                    ApplicationId = appID,
                    TokenExpireTime = 0,
                    CaptchaSid = captcha_sid,
                    CaptchaKey = captcha_key,
                    Settings = Settings.All
                });
            }
        }

        if (api.IsAuthorized) UserLogged?.Invoke(api);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex.Data != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Message: {ex.Message}\r\n \r\n Stack: {ex.StackTrace}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Поставьте брейкпоинты на все authorize, пока не понятно, какой из методов возвращает исключение, попробуйте пошагово найти место, где всё прерывается. Пометьте в коде вопроса, где это мпсто. Когда найдете, смотрите, что именно улетает серверу, может проблема с кодировками, может вообще что угодно быть.

Comment: @aepot вылетает на 75 строчке `api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams()...`, отправляется всё по нужному формату, попробую поиграться с кодировками. Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: строчки в коде не пронумерованы, добавьте в код комментарий `// вылетает здесь`, пожалуйста.

Comment: @aepot добавил, первый `api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams()...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, к чему я пришёл, с вероятностью в 99.9% процентов, это ограничение от ВК. Если у кого будет такая-же проблема, то может помочь прямая авторизация, но тут есть маленькая проблема. Почитайте [Прямая авторизация](https://vk.com/dev/auth_direct).